# jQuery Validation - prevent submit on remote

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to prevent form from submitting when remote call returns **true** as result. How can I do this?

The JS code:

```
var userForm = $('#user-form');

userForm.validate({
    rules : {
        email : {
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: userForm.find('#uniqueUrl').val() + '/isUniqueEmail',
                type: 'POST',
                data: function(){
                    return $('#email').val()
                },
                complete: function(data){
                    if(data.responseText.trim() == 'true'){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Server side:

```
public function isUniqueEmail()
    {
        $result = $this->users->isUniqueEmail($this->input->post('email'));

        if($result):
            echo false;
        else:
            echo true;
        endif;
    }
```

Comment: You're asking for the exact opposite of how it was designed to work. If you want to block the submit, you'd send a `false` from the server. ***Why*** are you wanting to do this?  A `true` response from server is supposed to indicate that it "passed" validation.  Are you really just wanting to suppress the error message?

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `data` option since the field's value is already sent by default.

Comment: I am returning "true" or "false" as a string from the server (echoing the result). I should return boolean?

Comment: Yes, echo boolean.  `false` is what will prevent the submit.

Comment: I changed server side code and now is working (server side code is now same as edited question). Now I need to bind message to the error (at the moment message is 1).

Comment: Replace the `false` with a JSON string... that will become the message.

Comment: @Sparky - I should add **echo json_decode('false')**? I am not very good with JS and JSON...

Comment: No, instead of `echo false`, do `echo json_encode('this name is taken');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60575/discussion-between-sasha-and-sparky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I need to prevent form from submitting when remote call returns **true** as result."*

That's backwards.  You would return `false` to block the submit and trigger the validation message.

You don't need the `data` option since the plugin sends the field value by default.  You also don't need the `complete` option as the plugin captures the server response automatically.

---

JavaScript:

```
var userForm = $('#user-form');
userForm.validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: userForm.find('#uniqueUrl').val() + '/isUniqueEmail',
                type: 'POST'  // default is GET
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Server-side:

```
public function isUniqueEmail()
{
    $result = $this->users->isUniqueEmail($this->input->post('email'));

    if($result):
        // setting message in PHP allows you to dynamically have any message
        echo json_encode('name is already taken');
    else:
        echo true;
    endif;
}
```

---

**ALTERNATE**

(Custom error message set in JavaScript)

JavaScript:

```
var userForm = $('#user-form');
userForm.validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: userForm.find('#uniqueUrl').val() + '/isUniqueEmail',
                type: 'POST'  // default is GET
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            remote: "name is already taken"
        }
    }
});
```

Server-side:

```
public function isUniqueEmail()
{
    $result = $this->users->isUniqueEmail($this->input->post('email'));

    if($result):
        echo false;
    else:
        echo true;
    endif;
}
```

---

**DOCUMENTATION**:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/